# From Rocky8 render Farm "No OpenCL platform has the specified device type (HOUDINI_OCL_DEVICETYPE): GPU." error

Tags: render, houdini, rocky-os

@Farm spec.

- 2 x Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6226R CPU @ 2.90GHz (32 cores, 64 logical) with 256904MB
- Rocky Linux 8.9 (Green Obsidian), Linux kernel 4.18.0-513.18.1.el8_9.x86_64
- NO GPU
- Tractor-2.4

@Error.

- No OpenCL platform has the specified device type (HOUDINI_OCL_DEVICETYPE): GPU.
  Falling back to built-in CPU OpenCL driver (see HOUDINI_USE_HFS_OCL)
  454493: Fatal error: Segmentation fault (sent by pid 0)
  -- TRACEBACK BEGIN --
  Traceback from hython 19.5.435 (Compiled on linux-x86_64-gcc9.3):
  stackTrace(UTsignalHandlerArg) <libHoudiniUT.so>
  signalCallback(UTsignalHandlerArg) <libHoudiniUT.so>
  UT_Signal::UT_ComboSignalHandler::operator()(int, siginfo_t*, void*) const <libHoudiniUT.so>
  UT_Signal::processSignal(int, siginfo_t*, void*) <libHoudiniUT.so>
  -- TRACEBACK END --

@Tried.

- Installing Intel OpenCL.
- Edited Houdini.env ("HOUDINI_USE_HFS_OCL=0" and "HOUDINI_OCL_DEVICETYPE=CPU") Doesn't work

@Question.

Artists are able to render on their personal PCs, but continue to encounter the same error when sending jobs to the render farm. Even after installing Intel OpenCL on the render farm, the problem remains unresolved. If anyone knows a solution to this issue, your assistance would be greatly appreciated.